# how to make Sidebar Panel change as you move to different PanelTab?

Tags: shiny

I would like the filters in my sidepanel to change as I move from Tab 1 to Tab 2, to Tab 3, etc..

I have the following code, but it is not working as desired. I suspect there is something wrong with the observeEvent function in server and the conditionalPanel in the UI. I have been trying different options, but it's not happ.  I welcome any suggestions.

```
source("a_chart.R")
source("b_chart.R")



# Define UI ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h2("Widgets"),
      
      p("We are going to place filters in this sidepanel"),
      
      helpText("Build a widget"),
      
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabseleted=='Tab 1'",
                       
                       h4("sidepanel for b"), 
                       selectInput("firm_as",
                                   label = "Firm",
                                   choices = c(unique(df_a$Name)),
                                   multiple = TRUE
                       ),
                       selectInput("date_as",
                                   label = "Date from",
                                   choices = c(unique(df_a$EndDate))
                       )),
      
      
      
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabseleted=='Tab 2'",
                       
                       h4("sidepanel for b"), 
                       selectInput("firm_bs",
                                   label = "Firm",
                                   choices = c(unique(df_b$Name)),
                                   multiple = TRUE
                       ),
                       selectInput("dates_bs",
                                   label = "Date from",
                                   choices = c(unique(df_b$EndDate))
                       )),
      
    ),
    
    
    
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel( id="tabselected", 
                   
                   tabPanel("Tab 1", 
                            fluidRow(
                              h1("Tittle 1"),
                              br(),
                              column(6,
                                     plotlyOutput("a_lcr_G")),
                              column(6,
                                     plotlyOutput("a_lcr_N")),
                            ),
                            br(),
                            
                            fluidRow(
                              br(),
                              column(3,
                                     plotlyOutput("a_lcr_NX")),
                            )
                            
                   ),
                   
                   
                   tabPanel("Tab 2", 
                            
                            fluidRow(
                              h1("Title 2"),
                              br(),

                              br(),
                              column(6,

                                     plotlyOutput("b_p1p2_G")),
                              
                              column(6,

                                     plotlyOutput("b_p1p2_N")),
                            ),
                            br(),
                            br(),
                            fluidRow(

                              br(),
                              column(6,
                                     

                                     plotlyOutput("b_lcr_G")),
                              
                              column(6,

                                     plotlyOutput("b_lcr_N")),
                            )
                            
                   ),
                   tabPanel("tab3"),
                   tabPanel("tab4"),
                   tabPanel("tab10"),
      )
    )
  )
)







# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  
  observeEvent(input$tabseleted, {
    # Tab 1
    if (input$tabseleted == "tab1") {
      updateSelectInput(session, "firm_as", choices = unique(df_a$FirmLabel), selected = unique(df_a$FirmLabel))
      updateSelectInput(session, "date_as", choices = unique(df_a$EndDate))
      
      # Tab 2
    } else if (input$tabseleted == "tab2") {
      updateSelectInput(session, "firm_bs", choices = unique(df_b$FirmLabel), selected = unique(df_b$FirmLabel))
      updateSelectInput(session, "date_bs", choices = unique(df_b$EndDate))
      
      #   # Tab 3
      # } else if (input$tabseleted == "tab3") {

      #   updateSelectInput(session, "f", choices = unique(df_c$FirmLabel), selected = unique(df_c$FirmLabel))
      #   updateSelectInput(session, "d", choices = unique(df_c$EndDate))
      #   
      #   # Tab 4
      # } else if (input$tabseleted == "tab4") {
      #   updateSelectInput(session, "f", choices = unique(df_d$FirmLabel), selected = unique(df_d$FirmLabel))
      #   updateSelectInput(session, "d", choices = unique(df_d$EndDate))
    }
  })
  
  
  
  
  
  

  
  
  
  #B widget
  #updateSelectInput(session, "f", choices = unique(df_b$FirmLabel), selected = unique(df_b$FirmLabel))
  #updateSelectInput(session, "d", choices = unique(df_b$ReportingPeriodEndDate))
  
  
  df_a_subset = reactive({
    df_a %>% dplyr::filter(
      FirmLabel %in% (input$firm_as),
      ReportingPeriodEndDate >= anydate(input$date_as)
    )
  })
  
  
  
  df_b_subset = reactive({
    df_b %>% dplyr::filter(
      FirmLabel %in% (input$fim_bs),
      ReportingPeriodEndDate >= anydate(input$date_bs)
    )
  })
  
  
  #A output
  
  output$a_lcr_G <- renderPlotly({
    a1_chart(df_a_subset(),entity = c("G"))
  })
  
  output$a_lcr_N <- renderPlotly({
    a2_chart(df_a_subset(),entity = c("R"))
  })
  
  
  output$a_lcr_NX <- renderPlotly({
    a3_chart(df_a_subset(),entity = c("NG"))
  })
  
  
  
  
  # B output
  
  output$b_p1p2_G <- renderPlotly({
    b1_chart(df_b_subset(),entity = c("G"))
  })
  
  output$b_p1p2_N <- renderPlotly({
    b2_chart(df_b_subset(),entity = c("NG"))
  })
  
  
  output$b_lcr_G <- renderPlotly({
    b3_chart(df_b_subset(),entity = c("G"))
  })
  
  output$b_lcr_N <- renderPlotly({
    b4_chart(df_b_subset(),entity = c("NG"))
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ensure that the spelling in the tabsetPanel ID is exactly the same in all places.  You are missing a "c" in many places.  Also, you need to set `value =` to a value (say, tab1) that you can use in the conditional panel.  Lastly, at the start of the app, `input$tabselected` is NULL; you need an observer to set it to tab1.

Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      h2("Widgets"),
      
      p("We are going to place filters in this sidepanel"),
      
      helpText("Build a widget"),
      
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected=='tab1'",
                       h4("sidepanel for b"), 
                       selectInput("firm_as",
                                   label = "Firm",
                                   choices = names(cars),
                                   multiple = TRUE
                       ),
                       selectInput("date_as",
                                   label = "Date from",
                                   choices = names(pressure)
                       )),
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected=='tab2'",
                       
                       h4("sidepanel for b"), 
                       selectInput("firm_bs",
                                   label = "Firm",
                                   choices = names(airquality),
                                   multiple = TRUE
                       ),
                       selectInput("dates_bs",
                                   label = "Date from2",
                                   choices = names(airmiles)
                       )),
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel( id="tabselected", type = c("tabs"), selected = "tab1",
                   
                   tabPanel("Tab 1", value="tab1",
                            fluidRow(
                              h1("Tittle 1"),
                              br(),
                              column(6, plotOutput("p1")),
                              column(6, plotOutput("p2"))
                            ),
                            br(),
                            fluidRow(
                              br(),
                              column(9,    plotOutput("p3"))
                            )
                   ),
                   tabPanel("Tab 2", value = "tab2",
                            fluidRow(
                              h1("Title 2"),
                              br(),     br(),
                              column(6,     plotOutput("p4")),
                              column(6,     plotOutput("p5"))
                            ),
                            br(),
                            br(),
                            fluidRow(
                              br(),
                              column(6,    plotOutput("p6")),
                              column(6,    plotOutput("p7"))
                            )
                   ),
                   tabPanel("tab3"),
                   tabPanel("tab4"),
                   tabPanel("tab10")
      )
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    if (is.null(input$tabselected)) {
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "tabselected", "tab1")
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$tabselected, {
    # Tab 1
    if (input$tabselected == "tab1") {
      updateSelectInput(session, "firm_as", choices = names(cars), selected = names(cars))
      updateSelectInput(session, "date_as", choices = names(mtcars))
      
      # Tab 2
    } else if (input$tabselected == "tab2") {
      updateSelectInput(session, "firm_bs", choices = names(cars), selected = names(cars))
      updateSelectInput(session, "date_bs", choices = names(mtcars))
      
    }
  })
  observe({print(input$tabselected)})
  
  output$p1 <- renderPlot(plot(cars))
  output$p2 <- renderPlot(plot(pressure))
  output$p3 <- renderPlot(plot(cars))
  output$p4 <- renderPlot(plot(airquality))
  
  output$p5 <- renderPlot(plot(cars))
  output$p6 <- renderPlot(plot(pressure))
  output$p7 <- renderPlot(plot(airquality))
 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your feedback was extremely helpful. The data in my charts are not rendering despite the filters being in working order.  Is there something wrong  with this reactive function?  df_b_subset = reactive({
    df_b %>% dplyr::filter(
      FirmLabel %in% (input$firm_bs),
      ReportingPeriodEndDate >= anydate(input$date_bs)
    )
  })

Comment: I can see the problem now. This reactive function is not filtering df_b. I don't see why (?) It's working in my app when I have 1 tab and not conditional panels.  df_b_subset = reactive({
    filtered_data <- df_b %>%
      dplyr::filter(
        FirmLabel %in% (input$firm_b),
        ReportingPeriodEndDate >= anydate(input$date_b)
      )
    print("df_b structure")
    str(df_b)
    print("df_b filter structure")
    str(filtered_data)
    #filtered_data
  })

Comment: data filtering is not a shiny issue.  Please ensure that the filtering works when you run it as R code without shiny.  Then you can incorporate it in the app.